# When is the ratio of largest number and smallest number when the sum and sum of squares is fixed

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, inequality

Given $n$ positive real numbers $a_1\geq a_2,\cdots\geq a_n>0$. Assume $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=b_1, \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2=b_2$. I want to find an upper bound on $\frac{a_1}{a_n}$, and the condition when this upper bound is achieved. My intuition is that the upper bound is achieved either $a_1=a_2=,\cdots=a_{n-1}>a_n$ or $a_1>a_2=a_3=\cdots a_n$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Some ideas: if for any fixed small $a_n$, the equations $a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}=b_1-a_n, a_1^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}^2=b_2-a_n^2$ has solutions, then one can let $a_n\to 0$, and the $\frac{a_1}{a_n}\to\infty$. To prevent this from happening, we need some conditions on $b_1, b_2$ so that $a_n$ has a positive lower bound. Specifically, one can use the following inequality

\begin{align}
\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}}{n-1} \leq \sqrt{\frac{a_1^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}^2}{n-1}}
\end{align}

We plug in $a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}=b_1-a_n$ and $a_1^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}^2=b_2-a_n^2$, after some calculations, we get $na_n^2-2b_1a_n+b_1^2-(n-1)b_2\leq 0$. Therefore, as long as $b_1^2-(n-1)b_2\leq 0$, then $a_n$ will have a positive lower bound. Then, my question is when $b_1^2-(n-1)b_2\leq 0$, what is the maximum value of $\frac{a_1}{a_n}$ and when the maximum is achieved?

Comment: Isn't the upper bound always infinite?  For $n>2$, can't we always take $a_n$ as close to $0$ as we like and fit the rest of the numbers to that?

Comment: @lulu Thank you for the response. I think what you said is correct. I have a follow-up question. If I can also have $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^k=b_k$ where $k=1,2,\cdots, n$ but I cannot solve these equations in closed form. Is there a bound on $\frac{a_1}{a_n}$.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't expect a lot of solutions in that case...the ordered sequence might be uniquely defined (or non-existant).  I suggest trying some examples.

Comment: @lulu thank you very much!

Comment: @lulu How about this example: $n = 3$, $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge a_3\ge 0$, $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 6$, $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 = 14$.  The minimum of $a_3$ is $\frac23(3 - \sqrt{3}) \approx 0.845299461$.

Comment: @RiverLi Thank you for giving this example. I think the answer also depends on $b_1, b_2$. One can use the following inequality to derive a bound on $a_n$:

\begin{align}
\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}}{n-1} \leq \sqrt{\frac{a_1^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}^2}{n-1}}
\end{align}

We plug in $a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}=b_1-a_n$ and $a_1^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}^2=b_2-a_n^2$, after some calculations, we get the following inequality on $na_n^2-2b_1a_n+b_1^2-(n-1)b_2\leq 0$. Therefore, as long as $b_1^2-(n-1)b_2\leq 0$, $a_n$ has a positive lower bound.

Comment: I guess that the minimum of $a_1/a_n$ is attained when $a_2 = \cdots = a_n$.
If $b_1^2 > (n-1)b_2$, I guess that the maximum of $a_1/a_n$ is attained when $a_2 = \cdots = a_{n-1}$.

Comment: @RiverLi we can only bound $a_n$ in cases where replacing it with zero gives a problem with C-S, am I right?

Comment: @DS Can you give more details?

Comment: In your example, if you set $a_3 \to 0$, You have $a_1+a_2 \approx 6$, $a_1^2+a_2^2 \approx 14$. But this is not possible by C-S. However, if we have a "good" value of $b_1,b_2$ so that we can have $a_3 \to 0$, then lulu's idea works. @RiverLi

Comment: @DS Yes, it is the following: If $b_1^2 \le (n-1)b_2$, then $a_1/a_n$ is unbounded ($a_n\to 0$). If $b_1^2 > (n-1)b_2$, then the maximum of $a_1/a_n$ can be obtained.

Comment: @Simon you should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4877526/edit) your comments into the question. This should serve as adequate context

Comment: Also, this question reeks of n-1 EV, but I'm not having much luck with it.

Comment: @RiverLi  Good point, the range of solvable initial conditions is more subtle than I thought.

Comment: @DS Hi, I have edited the questions to give more details.

Comment: @RiverLi Thank you for the comment. My intuition is similar that the maximum is attained when $a_2=a_3=\cdots=a_{n-1}$, but I haven't proved it. I will share it when I finish it.

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved using Lagrange multipliers. The objective function is

$$
f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=\log\frac{a_1}{a_n}-\lambda\sum_ia_i-\mu\sum_ia_i^2\;,
$$

where I took the logarithm of the ratio to be maximized in order to simplify the calculations. Setting the derivative with respect to $a_k$ for $k$ other than $1$ or $n$ to zero yields $\lambda+2\mu a_k=0$ and thus $a_k=-\frac\lambda{2\mu}$. The corresponding equations for $k=1$ and $k=n$, $\lambda+2\mu a_1=\frac1{a_1}$ and $\lambda+2\mu a_n=-\frac1{a_n}$, are linear in $\lambda$ and $\mu$ and can thus be solved to obtain

$$
-\frac\lambda{2\mu}=\frac{a_1^2+a_n^2}{a_1+a_n}\;,
$$

which is indeed between $a_1$ and $a_n$ and thus an admissible value of the other $a_k$. Substituting the $a_k$ into the constraints yields

\begin{eqnarray*}
(n-2)\frac{a_1^2+a_n^2}{a_1+a_n}+a_1+a_n&=&b_1\;,\\
(n-2)\left(\frac{a_1^2+a_n^2}{a_1+a_n}\right)^2+a_1^2+a_n^2&=&b_2\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Dividing the square of the first equation by the second yields

$$
\frac{\left((n-1)\left(1+\rho^2\right)+2\rho\right)^2}{(n-1)\left(1+\rho^2\right)^2+2\rho\left(1+\rho^2\right)}=\frac{b_1^2}{b_2}
$$

with $\rho=\frac{a_1}{a_n}$. This is a quartic equation for $\rho$ in terms of $\frac{b_1^2}{b_2}$. Substituting $\rho=0,1,\infty$ yields $\frac{b_1^2}{b_2}=n-1$, $n$ and $n-1$, respectively.

At the end of your derivation of a condition for the existence of an upper bound on $\rho$, you got the inequality the wrong way around: Substituting $a_n=0$ into $na_n^2-2b_1a_n+b_1^2-(n-1)b_2\le0$ yields $b_1^2-(n-1)b_2\le0$, so we need to have $b_1^2-(n-1)b_2\gt0$ and thus $\frac{b_1^2}{b_2}\gt n-1$ for this inequality to yield a positive lower bound on $a_n$. The analogous calculation with all $n$ variables shows that $\frac{b_1^2}{b_2}\le n$ must hold for the two constraints to be compatible.

Thus $\frac{b_1^2}{b_2}$ lies between $n-1$ and $n$, and in this range the maximal ratio $\rho$ varies from $1$ to $\infty$ according to the above quartic equation. Substituting this maximal value of $\rho$ into one of the constraint equations above then allows the corresponding values of $a_1$ and $a_n$ to be calculated.

Comment: thank you very much for the response! Just to confirm, the equation in terms of $\rho$ is a fifth-order polynomial equation since the denominator has the term $\rho(1+\rho^2)^2$. right?

Comment: @Simon: Good catch! No, it’s actually quartic, that last square was a typo. Dividing the second equation by $a_n^2$ and multiplying by $\left(a_1+a_n\right)^2$ yields

$$(n-2)\left(1+\rho^2\right)^2+(1+\rho)^2\left(1+\rho^2\right)=(n-1)\left(1+\rho^2\right)^2+2\rho\left(1+\rho^2\right)\;.$$

I fixed it.